# "Route [login] not defined." Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

i have a small project and it totally works fine on my localhost, but once i did share it on shared hosted :
i get two kinds o errors don't know why

> 1 -> "Route [login] not defined."

```
 public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {
        return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
}
```

> 2-> 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel 5

while trying make some post request
Please need help

Comment: share ur web.php

Comment: share your routes file and the code where the error roots